# Homepage's content is dependent on the custom field values (set automatically), how do I get homepage to update without manually updating page?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions, custom-field, query-posts

I have a custom field in my home page called "Featured posts". There are two fields: title and post. The post field returns *post_object* with post_type as *posts*. In my functions.php I have added the following function:

```
function my_post_object_query($args, $field, $post)
{
    $args['orderby']= 'date';
    $args['order']= 'DESC';
    $args['posts_per_page']= 1;
    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/name=post','my_post_object_query', 10, 3);
```

This function filters out and gets the most recent post. So when I go onto editing the homepage, the value of the post changes depending on what is the most recent post. This field is used in the template to show the content, however this content does not change automatically when the recent post changes. To apply the change, I have to go to the homepage and click *update* despite the custom field value already being changed by my functions.php. Is there a way for the page to update when the custom field value changes?

Hope I've explained my problem clear enough. Thanks.